# How to Loop Through Grouped Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I'm super new to python, but diving right in to try to figure out a real world problem using analysis tools like pandas.

I've imported the data from a csv already, but here's a small replication of the data:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'SKU': [22335, 22335, 22335, 22335, 33442, 33442, 33442, 33442],
                'Date': ['2019-12-31', '2020-01-07', '2020-01-14', '2020-01-21', '2019-12-31', '2020-01-07', '2020-01-14', '2020-01-21'],
                'Urgent': [10,8,4,20,50,45,65,32],
                'Delivered': [4,7,12,10, 35,75,23,42]})
```

There are two item SKU numbers, 22335 and 33442, a week starting date, weekly urgent requests for equipment and weekly equipment delivered quantities. At this point I have figured out how to calculate over the entire data set a for loop that for each row references the previous row's calculated value:

```
# Create new numeric column 'Result'
df['Result'] = np.nan

# Assign initial value for the first row of 'Result' (Should be first row in each SKU group)
df.loc[0, 'Result'] = df.loc[0, 'Delivered'] + df.loc[1, 'Delivered'] - df.loc[0, 'Urgent']

# Loop through each row except for last row to calculate
for i in range(1, len(df)-1):
    df.loc[i,'Result'] = max(df.loc[i-1, 'Result'], 0) + df.loc[i+1, 'Delivered'] - df.loc[i, 'Urgent']

print(df)
```

However, the next step for me is to perform the above only for each individual SKU (22335 and then 33442 separately). I have tried ranking each row by SKU by date using groupby, but I can't figure out how to reference this in my loop:

```
# Convert Date datatype
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# Use groupby to create ranking by SKU and Date
df['SKURank'] = df.groupby('SKU')['Date'].rank(ascending = True).astype('int64')
```

I've tried unsuccessfully to define a function that can reference it's own output for each iteration and then call that with an .apply style loop, but to be honest I'm totally lost on that.

I've also attempted to abide by the split, apply, combine principle and group my data by SKU, apply the loop, and then combine all rows back together, but again I really don't know where to start.

Here are my main questions:

**What kind of loop should I use to perform the same task as the above code (return an initial value for the first row in the group and then loop through each subsequent row) for each individual SKU group?**

**If the recommended form of loop (regardless of performance, I'm not that high-speed yet) requires that I define a function beforehand, how would I create a function that references it's own output for each row subsequent to the first row for each SKU?**

## ***UPDATE:***

## oh god. dear god what have I created... it's... it's disgusting...

Yes, I created a giant for loop with nested if statements. And yes, it's horrendous. And no, it doesn't do everything I need it to like perform the loop on the last row of the dataframe. If any part of the below makes sense and you can point me in the direction of how to make this actually functional, I'd appreciate some advice.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create dataframe for two SKUs, a weekly process date, urgent requested quantity, and delivered quantity
df = pd.DataFrame({'SKU': [22335, 22335, 22335, 22335, 33442, 33442, 33442, 33442],
                    'Date': ['2019-12-31', '2020-01-07', '2020-01-14', '2020-01-21', '2019-12-31', '2020-01-07', '2020-01-14', '2020-01-21'],
                    'Urgent': [10,8,4,20,50,45,65,32],
                    'Delivered': [4,7,12,10, 35,75,23,42]})

# Create new numeric column 'Result'
df['Result'] = np.nan

# Convert Date datatype and create 3 necessary columns
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Result'] = np.nan
df['WeeklyMiss'] = np.nan
df['Logic'] = ''

# Create list of unique SKUs in dataframe
skulst = df.SKU.unique()

print(skulst)


# Set initial indeces value 
skunum = 0
i = 0

# While loop with nested for loop to iterate over the dataframe
while skunum <= len(skulst):
    for i in range(0, len(df)-1):
        # Calculate first SKU row
        if i == 0 and df.loc[i, 'SKU'] == skulst[skunum]: 
            df.loc[i, 'Result'] = max(df.loc[i, 'Delivered'] + df.loc[i+1, 'Delivered'] - df.loc[i, 'Urgent'], 0)
            df.loc[i, 'WeeklyMiss'] = min(df.loc[i, 'Delivered'] + df.loc[i+1, 'Delivered'] - df.loc[i, 'Urgent'], 0)
            df.loc[i, 'Logic'] = 'First Row'
        # Calculate next SKU rows
        elif i > 0 and df.loc[i, 'SKU'] == skulst[skunum] and df.loc[i+1,'SKU'] == skulst[skunum]:
            df.loc[i, 'Result'] = max(df.loc[i+1, 'Delivered'] + min(df.loc[i-1, 'Result'], df.loc[i, 'Delivered']) - df.loc[i, 'Urgent'], 0)
            df.loc[i, 'WeeklyMiss'] = min(df.loc[i-1, 'Result'] + df.loc[i+1, 'Delivered'] - df.loc[i, 'Urgent'], 0)
            df.loc[i, 'Logic'] = 'Next SKU Row'
        # Calculate last SKU row
        elif i > 0 and df.loc[i, 'SKU'] == skulst[skunum] and (df.loc[i+1,'SKU'] != skulst[skunum] or i == len(df)):
            df.loc[i, 'Result'] = max(df.loc[i-1, 'Result'] - df.loc[i, 'Urgent'], 0)
            df.loc[i, 'WeeklyMiss'] = min(df.loc[i-1, 'Result'] - df.loc[i, 'Urgent'], 0)
            df.loc[i, 'Logic'] = 'Last SKU Row'
        
            
        # Calculate first SKU row and switch to next SKU 
        elif i > 0 and i < len(df) and df.loc[i, 'SKU'] != skulst[skunum] and df.loc[i-1,'SKU'] == skulst[skunum] :
            df.loc[i, 'Result'] = max(df.loc[i, 'Delivered'] + df.loc[i+1, 'Delivered'] - df.loc[i, 'Urgent'], 0)
            df.loc[i, 'WeeklyMiss'] = min(df.loc[i, 'Delivered'] + df.loc[i+1, 'Delivered'] - df.loc[i, 'Urgent'], 0)
            df.loc[i, 'Logic'] = 'First SKU Row'
            if skunum + 1 <= len(skulst):
                skunum += 1
            else:
                df.loc[i, 'Result'] = max(df.loc[i-1, 'Result'] - df.loc[i, 'Urgent'], 0)
                df.loc[i, 'WeeklyMiss'] = min(df.loc[i-1, 'Result'] - df.loc[i, 'Urgent'], 0)
                df.loc[i, 'Logic'] = 'Last SKU Row'
                continue
    else:
        print(df)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [Group By: split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) guide from pandas documentation to see how you can iterate over groups.

Comment: Thanks Sinan. I was aware of that resource beforehand, but I've been trying to glean as much as possible from it. Unfortunately, it's just not clicking. I feel like I won't understand the fundamentals of more advanced grouped looping or iteration until I can recreate my loop as a predefined function.